# Export Webpage to XLS

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, xls

In my cakephp project I have a page with a report which lists a certain amount of products. 
I need users to be able to export this page as XLS.

The trick is that in my report's table there is a PICTURE field which I also need to put into the xls, in other words I need to export the whole thing not just only the data.

None of the examples I've seen online is capable of doing this.

Help appreciated guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library to export the page content.

If you provide more examples of the data structure I can show some examples but generally you'll have to map the data to the Excel document manually based on it's content.